# change in media query break point in magento2

Tags: magento2

In magento2, desktop view comes from media point 768. i want to change this view. Rather than 768 my desktop view should start from 992. For that i am overritting the value of @screen__m from 768 to 992. But my changes are not reflecting. What are the other changes which i need to make ? Any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This would not be a good practice to perform changes directly on to core files of Magento. I would suggest you to create your own theme followed by any of the Magento's default theme. For that please follow below steps:

1. Add your theme under `app/design/frontend/{Namesapce}/{theme-name}` 
   Below URL would give you proper overview about creating theme in
   Magento2

**URL:** 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Here you can add your own custom.less file with custom width variable `i.e @cutom_desktop_width: 992` and based on that you can write your own required conditions:

```
.media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__m) {
    .example-responsive-block {
        background: #ccf;
    }
    .example-responsive-block:before {
        content: 'Desktop styles ';
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

**Reference URL** : http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/docs/responsive.html

Comment: the suggested approach in the link http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html (1) works in developer mode but not in production mode (rage) >:(

Comment: it was somehow to do with specificity and the load order of the css, only on tablet the theme was loading before the magento/module files

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to create a few customer changes, you can add those in a `custom.less` file, but it seems like you want to do a global change of the site's break points.

Take a look at this page on the [Magento 2 Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/responsive-web-design/rwd-breakpoints.html)
that goes over the process of overriding the `_responsive.less` file. Because all the .less files in the site inherit from this files variable definition, you can define a new break point once and every file that uses that break point will be updated.

You still have to create a theme to house these files, and Akshay Jindal's link will show you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

the only things you have to do is do it:

1. Add **_theme.less** in your theme 
   /app/design/frontend/***YourVENDOR***/***YourTeme***/web/css/source/_theme.less
2. Run **grunt clean** and **grunt exec** for republis symlinks to the source files, then run grunt watch for track the changes and compilation CSS
3. Add `@screen__m: 992px;` variable in your **_theme.less**

Good luck! :)

See more on [Magento Documentation Grunt](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html)